# Is it possible to implement Server Side Events in Hunchentoot?

Tags: javascript, html, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I would like to create a web application with Hunchentoot that works as follows; A client tells the server application that it is interested in a certain table in the database. When a change in the table occurs the server pushes this information. I have not looked into WebSockets yet because I am interested in HTML5's Server Side Events. Is it possible to write a Huncentoot acceptor that pushes data to the client through Server Side Events

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, it should *just work* by following the protocol:

- send headers with content-type `text/event-stream`
- send events as UTF-8 strings separated by double newlines

In Hunchentoot, see `send-headers`, which would send the headers set so far on the `reply` object and returns a *binary* stream that you'd write your events to (seems that you'd need to convert your strings to UTF-8 binary yourself).